# How to change "-" to a letter for hangman (C)?

Tags: c

I am working on a hangman game where my word is hidden behind dashes and as the player guesses the correct the letters, they will turn to the word.

```
int numdashes;
char word[NUM_LETTERS_MAX] = { "Coding" };
char dash[NUM_LETTERS_MAX] = {"------"};
char guess;
char str[7] = "Coding";

int numletters = 6;
int numguesses;

int count;

int loopcount;
int i;
int k;

int main()
{

    printf("Your Word Is: %c", &dash);
    //printf("\nWord: %c", &dash);
    
    loopcount = 10;
    numguesses = 1;
    while (numguesses <= loopcount)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numletters; i++)
        {
            dash[i] = "-";
        }
        dash[numletters = '\0'];
    
        printf("\nPick a letter to guess: ");
        scanf_s(" %c", &guess);
    
        numguesses = numguesses + 1;
    
        for (int k = 0; k < numletters; k++)
        {
            if (guess == word[k])
                dash[k] = guess;
        }
    
        printf("\nYou are at Guess Number %d, Your word is at %c", numguesses, word);
    
    }
    /*for (int i = 0; i < numletters; i++)
    {
        dash[word[i]]++;
    }*/
    
    if (numguesses < 10)
    {
        printf("\n\n\nYou Won the Game, Your Awesome");
    }
    else (numguesses == 10);
    {
        printf("\n\n\nI'm Sorry, the word was %s", &word);
    }
```

I'm having a couple of problems. The first for loop isn't display my dashes "------". My other problem is that my array doesn't seem to work, so it isn't scanning the word for the user's input. Thanks

Comment: Alot of issues. Suggest you tackle one small sub-part of the task at a time. Get it right before moving to the next part. For starters: `printf("Your Word Is: %c", &dash);` should be `printf("Your Word Is: %s", dash);` and `dash[i] = "-";` should be `dash[i] = '-';`,

Comment: Also, I presume you want to print `dash` and not `word` in the loop. Again use `%s` not `%c` for strings: `printf("\nYou are at Guess Number %d, Your word is at %s", numguesses, dash);`

Comment: Please try for a [mre]. Ideally of only the first of your problems.

Answer (score 1):

The very first thing to learn as a C programmer is:

**How to set your compiler to a high warning level**

The second thing to learn is:

**Treat all warnings as erros**

If you do that, you'll be able fix a lot of the problems in the code your self.

The very first problem is that the posted code can't even compile. `NUM_LETTERS_MAX` is unknown which results in a compilation error. Secondly, there needs to be an additional `}` at the end of the code. Again, a compilation error.

When these two things are fixed, the following warnings is/may be given:

```
prog.c:23:28: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[10]’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("Your Word Is: %c", &dash);
                           ~^   ~~~~~
prog.c:32:21: warning: assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
             dash[i] = "-";
                     ^
prog.c:34:13: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
         dash[numletters = '\0'];
         ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.c:47:64: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
         printf("\nYou are at Guess Number %d, Your word is at %c", numguesses, word);
                                                               ~^               ~~~~
                                                               %s
prog.c:59:22: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
     else (numguesses == 10);
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
prog.c:61:48: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[10]’ [-Wformat=]
         printf("\n\n\nI'm Sorry, the word was %s", &word);
                                               ~^   ~~~~~
prog.c:62:5: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
     }
     ^
prog.c:37:9: warning: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
         scanf(" %c", &guess);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**Before executing your program, these warnings must be fixed**

One example:

```
prog.c:23:28: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[10]’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("Your Word Is: %c", &dash);
```

This tells you that you can't print a string using `printf("Your Word Is: %c", &dash);`. If you don't know how to print a string in C, you'll have to do some research. Look it up in a C book or search the net. But **don't just ignore the warning**.

To print a string use: `printf("Your Word Is: %s", dash);`

Now move on to the next warning:

```
prog.c:32:21: warning: assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
             dash[i] = "-";
```

This tells you that you can't change a single character by assign it `"-"`. Again - if you don't know how to change a single character, research that specific problem. But **don't just ignore the warning**. The answer is: `dash[i] = '-';`

Continue like that - remove the warnings one-by-one.

Once you have a clean compile (i.e. no errors, no warnings) then you can start looking at the programs functional behavior.